# Did Henry Ford say, "Jews control the business..."?

Tags: united-states, economics, quotes, antisemitism

A [search for the quote](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Jews+have+always+controlled+the+business%22) returns results from many websites

[image: Jews control Hollywood quote by henry ford]

It claims that Henry ford said,

> "Jews have always controlled the business... The motion picture influence of the United States and Canada... is exclusively under the control, moral and financial, of the Jewish manipulators of the public mind"

Did Henry Ford say this?

Comment: Made neutral, and also please avoid mentioning sites that don't really deserve the mindshare unless necessary :-)

Comment: The claim is likely to be true, Ford's antisemitism is well documented - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_International_Jew

Comment: This is very disappointing.  I thought the question was asking about Harrison Ford, so I was looking forward to more currently juicy gossip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ford was an [antisemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Ford#The_Dearborn_Independent_and_antisemitism), so such a quote is not out of character.

Many other sources attribute the quote to "The Dearborn Independent, 12-19 February 1921".

The quote is from two different articles. From [The Jewish Aspect of the "Movie" Problem](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_International_Jew/Volume_2/Chapter_31):

> If this is true, it is chargeable to the Jews themselves, for **Jews have always controlled the business**. That it is true is probable, for the most zealous lampooners of the Jews have been Jewish comedians. Non-Jews fail abjectly in endeavoring to portray the character.

From [Jewish Supremacy in Motion Picture World](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_International_Jew/Volume_2/Chapter_32):

> Who stands at the apex of this mountain of control? It is stated in the sentence: **The motion picture influence of the United States—and Canada—is exclusively under the control, moral and financial, of the Jewish manipulators of the public mind**.

It should be noted that Ford did not write all the articles himself. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dearborn_Independent) describes the process:

> Ford did not write the articles. He expressed his opinions verbally to his executive secretary, Ernest Liebold, and to William J. Cameron [...]. Cameron had the main responsibility for expanding these opinions into article form[...].

Comment: It's not paraphrased, it's right [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dx5YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Also, "The International Jew" is not a special edition of the Dearborn Independent, [it is a reprint of selected articles](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dx5YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) that appeared in the Dearborn Independent.

Comment: @ff524 thanks, I added it to the answer

Comment: it's still not accurate to say that it's paraphrased. It's just from a different article (in the same publication)

Comment: The quote "Jews have always controlled the business" is in "The Jewish Aspect of the Movie Problem" in the Feb. 12, 1921 issue of the Dearborn Independent, available [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dx5YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q&f=false). The second part of the quote is from "Jewish Supremacy in Motion Picture World" from Feb. 19, 1921 issue, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dx5YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Might also be worth noting that Ford [retracted](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1927/07/08/page/1/article/ford-recants-fight-on-jews-in-his-paper) these anti-Semitic articles in response to a lawsuit.

Comment: @ff524 thanks, now it should be correct

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what tim answered, the quote "Jews have always controlled the business" separately appears in a 1922 authorized biography of Ford, which was partially written by Ford.

In [The Amazing Story of Henry Ford](https://books.google.com/books?id=PnDhAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=%22Jews%20have%20always%20controlled%20the%20business%22&source=bl&ots=Xcy_tg6Ixr&sig=Bu_uqETcQ3SeyBgS1Wkn0yZJhLY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuwdn9pcPSAhWSZiYKHT7TCB8Q6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22Jews%20have%20always%20controlled%20the%20business%22&f=false), the quote "Jews have always controlled the business"  appears on page 183.  The page is titled "Jews Always Controlled Movie".

In fact, 7 chapters of Ford's biography are about Jews, with a whole chapter about the Jews and the movie business.